# How to make json array if config have more than one value?

Tags: python, json

I need to create correct Json, base on config values. For example if config have next key value: `channel_id = 1,2,3,4` I need to get json like: `channel_id" : [1,2,3,4]`, but now I am getting `"channel_id" : "1,2,3,4"`

```
myfilter = dict(
        client_id=config['client_id'], 
        channel_id=config['channel_id']
        )
x = json.dumps(myfilter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse/split your config value into a `list` first:

```
myfilter = dict(
    client_id=config['client_id'],
    channel_id=[x.strip() for x in config['channel_id'].split(",")]  # split and strip
)
```

Given that this will produce strings, you might want to turn them into integers first (i.e. `int(x)` instead of `x.strip()`).